# Image resource identifier to temp path on server

Tags: php, file

I have two functions (pseudo code)

```
function UploadImage($FilePath) {

    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($FilePath);

    // do some work on $image like resize, compress, etc

    $NewImage = imagecreatetruecolor($x, $y);
    imagecopyresampled($NewImage, $image, ...);

    //$NewImage now holds an image resource identifier (IRI) object.
    //SaveFile($NewImageToFilePathSomehow);
}

function SaveFile($FilePath) {

    // perform some other checks and do some stuff

    rename($FilePath, $NewPath);
}
```

My obvious choice is using [`imagejpeg`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php) to manually create a copy of the file on the server, pass on the path to `SaveFile` and then delete the file, manually again. I was wondering if there's a way to create a temp file like [`tmpfile`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.tmpfile.php) allows and pass on the path.

`SaveFile` is a generalized function which is also used else where so it's only logical attribute type is the path and not a File Handle (like an [`fopened`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) file stream).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`tempnam`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php) to generate a temp filename and pass that to `imagejpeg` as the `filepath` and also use it as the `filepath` for your `SaveFile`.

To ensure files are created in a `tmp` directory, use `sys_get_temp_dir()` as the `dir` in `tempnam`.

Comment: But would that have any problem because `SaveFile` would be moving this temporary file to a new location? What if php decided to remove the temp file on script execution completion like it does with `tmpfile` files. I would think's it's better to just create the normal file with `imagejpeg` anywhere and then passing the path to `SaveFile` because it will be moved anyways.

Comment: As far as I can tell from documentation, `tempnam` doesn't delete files created, it only creates files with a unique filename. If files are created in `tmp` dir, they may be deleted by PHP. So if `SaveFile` renames filename and by extension the filepath, to anything but the tmp dir, they won't be deleted.

Comment: Ah cool, yeah the docs don't mention deletion. I think skipping the tempnam would be faster and more cleaner. I'll create the file directly from `imagejpeg` somewhere and move it. No point in creating the file if `imagejpeg` is going to overwrite it as soon as it's created.